# Firebase: Flutter: Optimizing for stability: many Transactions vs. Batch writes vs. Set calls

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

A few months ago, a glorious soul here taught me about transactions. I may have gone a little overboard thinking they were they best thing since sliced bread. The problem they solved was obvious, guaranteed concurrent writes on a single doc. However, I've noticed already with as little as three closely timed function triggers that I produced the dreaded:
 ------------------------"10 ABORTED: Too much contention on these documents."...-------------------------

Optimizing for stability, my question is: Would it be best practice to use a mixed bag of these write calls for different situations? For example: if a cloud function is writing to a location where I do not expect contention, should it just be a set call? Instead of 4 transactions to various locations, should I use a batch?

Reading the Firebase limitations I assumed I was in the clear with max 60w/doc/sec. However, I've learned now that Transactions can timeout AND only try to write 5 times.

Some background on the app and the contention error: 
- It's a basic social media app.
- The contention error came from making three posts in close succession from a single user.
- Each post triggers a cloud function that does several transactions to link the post to appropriate places. i.e. followers, feed, groups, sends notifications, and sets activity feed docs for each follower.

Side question: Am I wrongly understanding that firebase can handle an app with this level of activity?

EDIT: I was aware of these firebase limitations early on and did my best work to keep documents and collections spread apart appropriately.

CODE EDIT: index.js: adminPostReview is the specific function to throw the error (did the best I could to simplify).
The specific transaction to throw the error, I believe, is the call to transactionDayIndexAdd().

```
function transactionDelete(docRef) {
    return db.runTransaction(async t => {
        var doc = await t.get(docRef);
        if (doc.exists)
            t.delete(docRef);
    })
}

// THIS FUNCTION. Is it bad to read and set two documents?
function transactionDayIndexAdd(docRef, dayPosted, postId, userId) {
    return db.runTransaction(async (t) => {
        var postMap = {};
        const doc = await t.get(docRef.doc(dayPosted));
        if (doc.exists) {
            postMap = doc.data().pids;
        } else {
            const indexDoc = await t.get(docRef.doc('index'));
            var newIndex = indexDoc.exists ? indexDoc.data().index : {};
            newIndex[dayPosted] = true;
            t.set(docRef.doc('index'), { 'index': newIndex });
        }
        postMap[postId] = userId;
        t.set(doc.ref, { 'pids': postMap });
    })
}

exports.adminPostReview = functions.firestore
    .document('/adminPostReview/{postId}')
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
        const postId = context.params.postId;
        const userId = change.before.data().ownerId;
        const approvedMaks = change.after.data().approvedMaks;
        const approvedRita = change.after.data().approvedRita;
        var promises = [];
        if (approvedMaks == false || approvedRita == false) {
            promises.push(transactionDelete(db.collection('posts').doc(userId).collection('userPosts').doc(postId)));
        }
        else if (approvedMaks == true || approvedRita == true) {
            var newPost = change.after.data();
            promises.push(postLive(newPost));
        }
        if (approvedMaks != null || approvedRita != null) {
            promises.push(transactionDelete(db.collection('activityFeed').doc(MAKS_ID).collection('feedItems').doc(`${postId}_review`)));
            promises.push(transactionDelete(db.collection('activityFeed').doc(RITA_ID).collection('feedItems').doc(`${postId}_review`)));
        }
    });

async function postLive(newPost) {
    const userId = newPost.ownerId;
    const postId = newPost.postId;
    const dayPosted = newPost.dayPosted;

    var postToFeed = newPost.postToFeed;
    var postToGroups = newPost.postToGroups;
    newPost.approved = true;
    delete newPost.postToFeed;
    delete newPost.postToGroups;

    var batch = db.batch();
    var promises = [];
    if (postToFeed == true) {
        batch.set(
            db.collection('posts').doc(userId).collection('userPosts').doc(postId),
            newPost
        );
        batch.update(
            db.collection('userActivity').doc(userId),
            'numPosts',
            admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
        )
        promises.push(batch.commit());
        promises.push(transactionDayIndexAdd(db.collection("feedRandom"), dayPosted, postId, userId));
        var querySnap = await db.collection('followers')
            .doc(userId)
            .collection('userFollowers')
            .get();
        querySnap.docs.forEach(async follower => {
            promises.push(transactionDayIndexAdd(
                db.collection('feedFollowing').doc(follower.id).collection('feedItems'),
                dayPosted, postId, userId));
            promises.push(transactionSet(db.collection('activityFeed').doc(follower.id)
                .collection('feedItems').doc(postId),
                {
                    media1Url: newPost.media1Url,
                    media2Url: newPost.media2Url,
                    postId: newPost.postId,
                    timestamp: newPost.timestamp,
                    type: 'newFollowingPost',
                    userId: userId,
                    userProfileImg: newPost.ownerProfileImg,
                    username: newPost.username,
                    displayName: newPost.displayName,
                }
            ));
            if (follower.data().notificationToken != null) {
                const payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: 'Someone you follow made a new post!',
                        body: `${newPost.username} has a new post.`
                    },
                    data: {
                        click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
                        vestiq_type: 'newFollowingPost',
                        vestiq_uid: follower.id,
                        vestiq_fid: userId,
                        vestiq_pid: postId,
                        vestiq_displayName: newPost.displayName,
                        vestiq_photoUrl: newPost.ownerProfileImg,
                        vestiq_username: newPost.username,
                    }
                };
                var user = await db.collection('users').doc(follower.id).get();
                if (user.data().notificationOp3 == true)
                    promises.push(pushNotification(follower.data().notificationToken, payload));
            }
        });
        if (postToGroups != null && postToGroups.length > 0) {
            promises.push(pushGroupPosts(postToGroups, userId, postId, newPost));
            return Promise.all(promises);
        } else return Promise.all(promises);
    }
    else if (postToGroups != null && postToGroups.length > 0) {
        promises.push(pushGroupPosts(postToGroups, userId, postId, newPost));
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }
}

async function pushGroupPosts(postToGroups, userId, postId, newPost) {
    var groupBatch = db.batch();
    postToGroups.forEach((gid) => {
        groupBatch.set(
            db.collection('groups').doc(gid).collection('posts').doc(postId),
            newPost,
        );
        groupBatch.set(
            db.collection('usersGroupPosts').doc(userId).collection(gid).doc(postId),
            { 'gid': gid, 'postId': postId },
        );
    });
    return push(groupBatch.commit());
}
```

Comment: Since we can't see your code or understand how exactly you intend for your transaction working, it's hard to say.  Please edit the question to show the specific code where you have too much contention, and explain the specific use case.

Comment: I wanted to avoid code specifics. But always glad to share code.

Comment: Thanks.  On Stack Overflow, sharing code is the *default* expectation.

Comment: makes sense haha. I'll make sure to improve on my future questions.

Comment: ok, I can confirm that the transaction in transactionDayIndexAdd() with the nested t.get and t.set is causing a problem. I separated the transaction into two with a boolean to determine if the second should run. I was able to post 5 times consecutively without any issue. I imagine nesting the t.get and t.set makes the transaction exponentially less likely to succeed? Will continue testing with a larger set of posts.

Comment: Were the last tests successful?

Comment: I haven't seen the issue since splitting that transaction in two. I don't exactly know the underlying mechanics of transactions, but logically what I did originally was silly lol

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the contention problem by splitting transactionDayIndexAdd() into two separate transactions. I flip a bool to determine if the second should run instead.

This leads me to believe that the nested t.get/t.set transaction significantly increases chances for contention issues. Since the split, I have not been able to reproduce the error. Here is the new transactionDayIndexAdd() for those who are curious.

HOWEVER, my original question still stands regarding optimising for stability.

```
async function transactionDayIndexAdd(docRef, dayPosted, postId, userId) {
    var dayAdd = 0;
    var promises = [];
    await db.runTransaction(async (t) => {
        var postMap = {};
        const doc = await t.get(docRef.doc(dayPosted));
        if (doc.exists)
            postMap = doc.data().pids;
        else {
            dayAdd = 1;
        }
        postMap[postId] = userId;
        t.set(doc.ref, { 'pids': postMap });
    });
    if (dayAdd == 1) {
        promises.push(db.runTransaction(async (t) => {
            const indexDoc = await t.get(docRef.doc('index'));
            var newIndex = indexDoc.exists ? indexDoc.data().index : {};
            newIndex[dayPosted] = true;
            t.set(indexDoc.ref, { 'index': newIndex });
        }));
    }
    return await Promise.all(promises);
}
```